# Vmware player 5.0.1 and kernel 3.7 will not complile

Tags: kernel, vmware

I downloaded current version of VMWare Player. I have kernel 3.7. When starting, it asked me to tell where the kernel was located.
So Vmware kernel modules did not compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to add a symbolic link to version.h:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-3.7.0-7-generic/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h /usr/src/linux-headers-3.7.0-7-generic/include/linux/version.h
```

then I run

```
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

Then it compiled

Comment: Article http://rglinuxtech.com/2012/11/18/vmware-9-0-1-not-so-clever-after-all/ helped to find the solution

Answer (score 1):

This is valid for any kernel version you currently have:

```
ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`/include/linux/version.h
```